# Configure LINQPad to work with NHibernate Profiler

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linqpad, nhibernate-profiler

I would like to profile my NHibernate queries that I run from LINQPad using NHibernate Profiler.

When I try to initialize the profiler using this:

`NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();`

**I get the following error:**

`The type or namespace name 'NHibernate' does not exist in the namespace 'HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

This strange because without initializing the profiler my NHibernate code in LINQPad executes as expected (therefore definitely finding the required NHibernate DLLs).

LINQPad is configured as follows:

Additional references:

- NHibernate.dll (3.2.0.4000)
- HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.v4.0.dll (1.0.0.920)
- ConformOrm.dll (2.0.0.0)
- ConformOrm.Shop.dll (2.0.0.0)
- IesiCollections.dll
- log4net.dll
- MyApplication.dll

Additional namespace imports:

- HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate

Stack trace for additional information:

```
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.Compile(String fileName, String[] sources, IEnumerable`1 assembliesToReference)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(IEnumerable`1 sourcesResources, IEnumerable`1 assembliesToReference, String assemblyName)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.RegisterAppenderUsingNHibernateLogger()
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.WrapLogger()
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.StartNHibernateProfiling()
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize(NHibernateAppenderConfiguration configuration)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HibernatingRhinos is generating code which it's then trying to compile and failing.

If you can track down the file created by `HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.Compile`, you should get a better clue as to why it's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks Joe, let me see what I can find.  BTW LINQPad is brilliant, great work.